# Запись в список из файла

Tags: python, list, int

Есть текстовый файл, следующего вида:

0 0 0 0

3 3 3 3

Необходимо считать все значения и выдать их в следующем виде:

[[0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3, 3]]

В текущей версии кода вывод следующий:

[['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['3', '3', '3', '3']]

Как сформировать список с объектами типа int, а не str не прибегая к использованию сторонних библиотек? (с помощью numpy всё работает, однако он начинает ругаться если во входном файле списки разной длинны, а для корректной работы программы списки ДОЛЖНЫ быть разной длинны)

```py
deg_seqs = []

with open("graph.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
for item in lines:
    temp = item.split()
    deg_seqs.append(temp)
print(deg_seqs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
with open('graph.txt', 'r') as file:
    deg_seqs = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in file]
```

Тут используется `map`, который применяет выбранную функцию к переданному списку:
`list(map(int, line.split()))` делает из `['1', '1', '1']` -> `[1, 1, 1]`